# How to test Javascript is equal to Apex as possible

Tags: apex, unit-test, javascript, code-coverage

1. How do you manage to test your Javascript code with the **same high standards** as your Apex code?
2. Which **frameworks** worked best for you?
3. Is there a way to **run JS tests from Apex Test** so that they run automatically when I upload my package?

Comment: I've heard great things about Jasmine. Don't think it's possible to run anything from `Apex`, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do you manage to test your Javascript code with the same high standards as your Apex code?

Treat unit testing in JavaScript the same as you would in Apex, making sure that as much of the code is covered as possible and always include assertions in the code.

> Which frameworks worked best for you?

Personally I love Laravel which is a PHP Framework, that works really well with [vue.js](https://vuejs.org) which does support [unit testing](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/unit-testing.html). However, you could use [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) although it seems that you'd need another framework called [Mocha](http://unitjs.com/guide/mocha.html). You could use [React.js](https://facebook.github.io/react/) which has [unit tests](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/test-utils.html) or [Angular.js](https://angularjs.org/), again with [unit testing](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing).

Really, the framework that works best for you is really subjective. Play with them and find your favourite, but in one way or another the aforementioned 4 support unit testing and are all powerful frameworks.

> Is there a way to run JS tests from Apex Test so that they run automatically when I upload my package?

Because JavaScript exists on the front end, you can't call JavaScript from the controller, the page is the output of the controller.

You *could* do something like this:

```
<apex:page>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function doSomething() {
            // Some testing code...
        }
    </script>
    <apex:outputText value={!callJavaScript} escape="false"></apex:outputText>
</apex:page>
```

---

```
public class myController {
    public String callJavaScript {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public myController() {
        callJavaScript = '<script>doSomething()</script>';
    }
}
```

But it's messy and doesn't really achieve anything worthwhile, again, Apex Unit Tests are designed to test Apex code and don't interact with Visualforce pages. Rather, within the Unit Test, you'd tell it what it might expect from URL Parameters, as an example, and what to do with it or what happens when it's not what's expected or null.

Even if you found a way to run JS unit tests from Apex unit tests, any failed JS tests executed on upload or deployment wouldn't fail the deployment, so bad or untested code would still get into production.

Personally, I'd say the absolute best practice is to write JS unit tests and, when you're happy with them, get them signed off. Treat JavaScript Unit Tests with the same respect as you do Apex Unit tests, just in two separate eco-systems.

**Edit**

I feel like I've been a bit ambiguous, the answer to your third question, I'm 99% sure is **no** (because we can only be 100% sure of death and taxes in life) because even if you wrote a unit test for the class above, Salesforce would say to itself: "Yes, if I was running in production, I would execute this code. But I'm not, I would set `callJavaScript` to that String, but that's all I'm going to do because I'm in a unit test".

The browser "compiles and executes" JavaScript so there's just no way I can see on upload/deployment to run JS unit tests in Apex code. Apex only cares about Apex and a String with `<script type="text/javascript">[...]` in it is as good to Apex as a String with `Hello world!`.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately a lot of JavaScript code is written inline in Visualforce pages so the JavaScript is deeply coupled to the rendered HTML. That pushes you into writing user interface tests rather than JavaScript tests where you use e.g. [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) to drive the UI and assert what happens to the DOM (so implicitly rather than explicitly testing the JavaScript).

Keeping the JavaScript entirely separate (e.g. in static resources) takes discipline. If you manage to do that, I assume that the [Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/) JavaScript test runner and [Jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io/) test spec language (that I've used for Angular JavaScript) would work for arbitrary JavaScript. Hooks up well to [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) too.

(We do push all separate JavaScript files through http://jshint.com/ from Jenkins to catch poor JavaScript coding at build time.)

Hopefully Salesforce will soon offer a JavaScript test environment for Lightning Components given that they are heavily JavaScript based.

Comment: Salesforce came up with Lightning CLI.
Lightning CLI kinda helps with JS formating and basics errors. Still no proper testing framework for lightning